# NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsformatter

I can not figure out how I convert a special date-string to NSDate. 
What I have:

```
NString * dateStr = @"2013-06-10T18:21:37";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate * dateD = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
NSTimeInterval interval = [dateD timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

also tried:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"];
```

with no luck.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a typo, you were setting dateFormat to a different formatter instance.

```
NString * dateStr = @"2013-06-10T18:21:37";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate * dateD = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: i corrected my question.It was an typo but not in the orignal code.

Comment: @sirsultan I guessed so, I just took the code as such and tried it. It was working perfectly.

Comment: @sirsultan Another possible mistake is the ambiguous position of month  and days. In the example provided it was ok. Can you cross check this in your original code.